# Guice injection and RequestFactory: Extending ServiceLayerDecorator

Tags: java, gwt, guice, requestfactory

I searched for a solution to use Guice Dependency injection together with `RequestFactory`.
I stumbled upon this: https://github.com/etiennep

It wasn't working for me so I changed the InjectedServiceLayerDecorator.java implementation to this:

https://github.com/opncow/injected-requestfactory/blob/master/src/main/java/com/trycatchsoft/gwt/requestfactory/InjectedServiceLayerDecorator.java

Now my questions are:

Can something be done better regarding the caching mechanism of `RequestFactory` (Is it still working?)?
What is `getTop()` and `getNext()` (in ServiceLayerDecorator) for? 
And is it correct / safe to use `getTop()` in this place?

Sorry thought too complicated!
It was as easy as:

```
Class<?> serviceClazz = resolveServiceClass(requestContext);
        return injector.getInstance(serviceClazz);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is getTop() and getNext() (in ServiceLayerDecorator) for?

ServiceLayer uses a chain of responsibility pattern: in cases your decorator has nothing specific to do, it should delegate to the next decorator in the chain (returned by `getNext`) by calling the same method with the same arguments. If your decorator changes the arguments, or needs to call another method, it should call it on `getTop` so the call is routed through all decorators, and not just the ones after itself in the chain.

Your use of `getTop` is thus correct and safe (have a look at the LocatorServiceLayer from GWT, that's exactly what it does).

But your code (and Etienne's one!) can actually be made simpler and better: simply override `createServiceLocator` to get an instance from your injector (same as `createLocator`).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I now use createServiceLocator and its much easier and working perfectly.